# How to specify nmap to add redirect address?

Tags: linux, ping, nmap

I'm trying to `ping` the health of VM's using `nmap` utility.

```
# nmap -v -n -sP  192.168.102.116
 Host 192.168.102.116 appears to be down.
 Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -P0
 Nmap finished: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 2.006 seconds
```

then I tried with direct `ping`, as it shows the host reachable. then I found the next hop directive in the `ping` output.

```
# ping 192.168.102.116
 PING 192.168.102.116 (192.168.102.116) 56(84) bytes of data.
 From 192.169.64.129: icmp_seq=1 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.169.64.149)
 64 bytes from 192.168.102.116: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=15.6 ms
```

Env:- RHEL 5.11 nmap version - 4.11

```
$ netstat -r
  Kernel IP routing table
  Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt 
  Iface
  10.10.2.0      *               255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 
  eth0
  169.254.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 
  eth0
  default         10.10.2.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 
  eth0
```

#### Question

How to do it with the `nmap` utility? by specifying to `ping` host from the redirect address?

I found a similar option with `fping` utility `--icmp-redirect-addr`, likewise is there any option can specify next hop address so that `nmap` to scan the host properly

Note: this is production as I can only try with `ping` and `nmap`. For scanning many hosts in parallel ping took more time, so need to stick in `nmap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How come `nmap` is taking less time? I can't seem to reproduce that. In your case it is giving you a lower time since it can't reach the server so those times can't be compared.

`ping -c1 ip-to-check` will only send one probe and will take very little time.

In your case, and according to your outputs there seems to be some routing problem, check your routes since your `ping` is receiving a redirection. Use `traceroute` to see the hops your ping goes through and check your routes.

You can try to use `nmap -sn --traceroute` and see if that command accepts the redirection as `ping` does, but the best would be to check those routes since your IPs are on a different network and the route you have established to reach your destination is being redirected as the `ping` command shows.

Since it is easier to see my results here I edited my post instead answering your comment:

```
root@Caronte:~# time ping -c1 10.50.1.105
PING 10.50.1.105 (10.50.1.105) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.50.1.105: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.127 ms

--- 10.50.1.105 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.127/0.127/0.127/0.000 ms

real    0m0,002s
user    0m0,000s
sys     0m0,000s
root@Caronte:~# time nmap -sn -Pn 10.50.1.105

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-07-25 15:25 CEST
Nmap scan report for 10.50.1.105
Host is up.
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.00 seconds

real    0m0,005s
user    0m0,000s
sys     0m0,004s
```

As you can see, on my machine `nmap` takes more time than `ping`.

Comment: nmap -v -n -sP -iL <iplist> which works pretty faster than normal ping{in loop}